# How to connect AWS Opensearch dashboard with MySQL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-opensearch, opensearch-dashboards

I want to connect my MySQL database with AWS Opensearch service, where i can see MySQL data in my Opensearch Dashboard.

I am excepting the steps or demo on "how to connect MySQL with AWS Opensearch Service.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I have updated the Question.